# creating integer array

Tags: iphone

hi i am new iphone programmer
i want to know that can we create array of integer,array of strings....etc seperatly
like c++
if yes then how....
 i have read about the example given on this site but that is c style of array....
please reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` is the standard array class in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch. It can contain objects, but not primitives.

You can store integers in an array by wrapping them with an `NSNumber` object like so:

```
NSNumber *myInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Then you can store it in an array like so:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myInt];
```

Comment: i tried this one but problem is that i want to store man values in it but it does not supporting

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]
                                       , [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]
                                       , [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3]
                                       , nil];
```

[Here's](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) a reference.